How can I sync the volume of an audiosource with how a material change alpha?
I am making a flickering light prefab, and have already made a shader and a material that make it turn on and off erratically.
I also want the light to emit a buzzing sound when it's turned on, but I don't know how to make the shadergraph output the alpha value so I can use it as the Sudiosource's volume

You can't make the shader graph output the alpha value to a C# script, but you can go the other way, and provide an alpha value from a C# script. You'd move your flickering calculation CPU-side, and use it to drive both the audio and the material's alpha parameter.

Thanks for the tip. I was trying to do it by having a function to modify one of the input variables of the shader but I couldn't manage to read it's value.

Can you edit your question to show us what you tried?

I'll add screenshots of the shadergraph later this evening

Remember that anything you compute in the graph cannot be read from the C# side. So to repeat, this flickering calculation should not be done in the graph if you want to use the value to control audio from C#.
